# Internationalization for vue 3 vite with i18n

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vite, vue-i18n

I'm currently trying to internationalize my vue 3 vite project with "@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n". The problem I am facing here, is that i currently have to import and setup the t variable for every component to use it. 
**example component:**

```html
<template>
  t('translation')
</template>

<script>
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
export default {
  setup(){
    const {t} = useI18n();
    return {t}
  },
};
</script>
```

My question is, if its possible, what is the best way to  make the variable "t" global? I cant find any examples/help on this, since they all import it into every compoenent. All help would be apreciated! :)
For reference, here are the relevant files.

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    vueI18n({
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/locales/**')
    })
  ]
})
```

**main.ts:**

```js
import i18n from './i18n';
const app = createApp(App);
app.use(i18n);
app.mount("#app");
```

**i18n.js:**

```js
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import messages from '@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n/messages'

export default createI18n({
  legacy: false,
  locale: 'no',
  messages
})
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The i18n plugin registering using `app.use(i18n)` make a global function `$t` available for all the children components :

```html
<template>
  {{$t('translation')}}
</template>
```

This function is also available in option api and you could it like :

```js
mounted() {
  console.log(this.$t('translation'))
}
```

But you should add `globalInjection: true,` to i18n config as follows :

```js
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import messages from '@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n/messages'

export default createI18n({
  legacy: false,
  locale: 'no',
  globalInjection: true,
  messages
})
```

BONUS :

Change the locale by watching the getter inside `App.vue` then set locale:

```js
<script>

import { defineComponent, onMounted, watch } from "vue";
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";
import { useStore } from "vuex";


export default defineComponent({
  name: "app",
  data() {
    return {};
  },

  setup() {
    const i18n = useI18n();
    const store = useStore();

    watch(()=>store.getters.currentLang,(newVal) => { //watch the getter
      i18n.locale.value = store.getters.currentLang;
    },{
      immediate:true
    });
  },
});
</script>
```

Comment: How can we change locale when action triggered??

Comment: I found that you can use `$i18n.locale = 'es'` for example to change to spanish

Comment: Yes in options api or template you could do that

Answer (score 17):

I have an additional example to show of accessing the global composer instance in vue-i18n **v9**:

*i18n.js*

```
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n';
import en from './locales/en';
import fr from './locales/fr';

const i18n = createI18n({
    legacy: false,
    locale: 'en',
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    messages: {
        en,
        fr,
    },
});

export default i18n;
```

*main.js*

```
import i18n from './i18n.js';

...

app.use(i18n);
```

Then you can import the instance into any file, such as vue-router's beforeEnter hook or vuex, etc.

```
import i18n from '../i18n.js';

console.log('i18n', i18n.global);

// to change locale:
i18n.global.locale.value = 'en';
```

You access it via `i18n.global`. it is the same instance that is returned via `useI18n()` from the 'vue-i18n' package.